# Site Icon, and Images yeilding 404 error

Tags: master-page, site, 404, image, file-icons

I am currently trying to change the site icon. I have uploaded the icon picture to the Style Library in a folder titled Demo.

The name of the picture is Logo and it is a .png file.

When I give the relative URL in the url box, I get a 404 error page even know the url is correct.

Is there an additional feature that has to be enabled on the site. I have doubled check that the image has been published.

Comment: Usually the site just displays a red cross where the picture is supposed to be if it isn't found. Are you sure there isn't anything else in the masterpage which could cause this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if you have installed any 3rd party SharePoint add-ons that may have modified the web.config.  Also check for any manual web.config changes.

Comment: We did, we used a branding add-on. I was unaware of this since I wasn't involved.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the URL in the form of /SiteAssets/Photo1.png? Please note the leading slash - it's needed. I even have tested your exact location: /Style%20Library/TestFolder/Photo1.png

Comment: Yes definetly got the leading slash.